# Non-dynamic insertion of youtube player iframe doesn't fire events

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using youtube's iframe api

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

I want to write the `<iframe>` tag by hand (not insert it asynchronously). The docs suggest this is possible

> If you do write the tag, then when you construct the YT.Player object,
>   you do not need to specify values for the width and height, which are
>   specified as attributes of the  tag(...)

But when I insert the `<iframe>` tag directly

```
  <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and remove the dynamic tag generation

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

(and width, height and id from the options when creating a new player instance)

I cannot get the function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady to be called. I've tried using the dynamic insertion of the script tag and it works. The docs are a bit unclear about what's needed for when you don't dynamically inserted - so I'd be grateful for advice

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your iframe element already present on the page, you still have to load the iframe javascript library, as it's that library which calls `onYouTubeIFrameAPIReady`. So your code should look something like this:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
</script>
```

Note that in this case, the value you pass to `onYouTubeIFrameAPIReady` is the ID of your iframe, rather than the ID of a div ... the library will recognize this is an iframe and hook into the existing video rather than trying to dynamically generate an iframe for you.

Comment: That makes sense. I did try that but I will try again and let you know. Cheers